# reformat if statements, functions in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I know the general format of Xcode is to have an if statement proceed like this:

```
if(condition){

    statements

}
```

but I'd like to have them be displayed as

```
if(condition)

{

    statements

}
```

same with functions and other items like these. I was wondering if Xcode had an option to change it. I just like my code like that more even though it takes more lines. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Ok so when you type it out just put it like that, this is very unclear what you actually want from us. Voting to close

Comment: I want the brackets to be displayed so it's on the next line, when I type out an if statement it automatically goes to the first format, I'd like to use autocomplete so it displays as the second format

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this but not built in to Xcode. [Uncrustify](https://github.com/bengardner/uncrustify) is an Xcode plugin that you can configure to reformat your classes syntax to your liking. I set up keyboard shortcut to run it. It's a bit technical but worth the effort if you really must have it your way. The other option is to edit the default templates for Xcode. That will only format the default boilerplate code. Anything you write will need to be formatted by you. Try Uncrustify.

Comment: Thank you, I'm having trouble installing the plugin since the developer library in application support is not there anymore since Xcode 4.3 from what I'm seeing on the internet, how can I install this plugin, or for that matter any plugin?